# Find multiple elements within certain element in Cypress

Tags: testing, react-redux, automated-tests, e2e-testing, cypress

Code:

```
<div class="title">
  <button data-testid="tg-menu" class="hitbox-border">
    <img src="asldij">
  </button>
  <div class="menu" data-testid="menu-list">
    <button class="text-left" data-testid="option-1">
      <span>Menu Option 1</span>
    </button>
    <button class="text-left" data-testid="option-2">
      <span>Menu Option 2</span>
    </button>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="flex-grow">
        <hr class="lightgrey-border">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-grow">
        <hr class="lightgrey-border">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="text-left" data-testid="option-3">
      <span>Menu Option 3</span>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tool: Cypress

I have code similar to above and want to do couple of things easily without using -- Class Names when selecting elements.

I can do it as cy.get('[data-testid="menu-list"]').children('button') but wanted to get it similar to xpath - contains...as above example is simple but some of the things are more difficult in dom.

Questions:

1. Find All the Button Names under menu list.

   Is there one line cy.get() I can use similar to 
   By.xpath(`//div[@data-testid='menu-list']//button[contains(@data-testid,'option-')]`) ?
2. Is there easy way to translate selenium xpath to cypress...

Note: I know there is extension for xpath for cypress not sure if performance wise it is good or not.

Answer (score 3):

1. AFAIK it's not possible to use something like `contains` in a css selector (which is what `cy.get` is using). However, your can get all the buttons and invoke `each` on them to get the value of `data-testid`
   For example:

   cy.get('[data-testid="menu-list"]').children('button').each(btn => cy.log(btn.getAttribute("data-testid")))

In case you have buttons that their `data-testid` attribute does not start with `option-` and you want to filter them out, I'd suggest to have 2 different data attributes: one for the filtering which is doesn't have to be unique (e.g. `data-testid='option'`), and another one that holds the interesting value (e.g. `data-value='1'`)

2. The cypress-xpath extension is the only way I know of to use xpath with Cypress. Regarding performance I don't have any data. I believe that it's slower then `cy.get` with css selector, just like it's in Selenium. But I also believe that in most cases it's pretty meaningless. As with any performance question, the best answer is to perform your own measurements in the context that's relevant to you.